# Adding JavaScript closure to chart data refresher

Tags: javascript, closures

Here's a script that fetches data for a chart and repeats the operation every 30 seconds. Problem is that there's a memory leak and some research tells me that I need to add a JavaScript closure. However, since I'm not very familiar to JavaScript, I'm failing to get it working.

Here's the result of my last attempt:

```
fetch('log_chart.txt')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (text) {
        let series = csvToSeries(text);
        renderChart(series);
    setTimeout(trigger, 30000);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

  function trigger() {
    setTimeout(function (){
      fetch('log_chart.txt')
      .then(function (response) {
      return response.text();
      })
      .then(function (text) {
      let series = csvToSeries(text);
      renderChart(series);
      })
        .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }, 30000);
    });
  }
```

**The first part gets the data and renders the chart, also sets it to repeat after 30 seconds. The second part should repeat the above and it should never stop.**

**Problem is that it does stop after second update - so the second `setTimeout` isn't working as I'd expect.**

How should I do it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should use `setInterval` instead, which runs a certain function every x amount of seconds. It should also solve your memory leak problem, which can be caused by the use of `setTimeout`, as it is async, meaning that the code continues to add more and more `setTimeout` while still running other code. This holds up unnecessary memory. More about that here: [How does setTimeout() create a memory leak in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088308/how-does-settimeout-create-a-memory-leak-in-this-code/23178832)

As for the solution:

```
function trigger() {
    fetch("log_chart.txt")
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (text) {
            let series = csvToSeries(text);
            renderChart(series);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

trigger()
setInterval(trigger, 30000)
```