# JavaScript setInterval() and setTimeout() freezing browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm woking in a mobile friendly monitoring tool based on rrdtool.

All working fine but when I have the webpage opened for more that 1 hour freezes my computer.

I use this snippet for refresh the images.

```
<?php

if(!isset($includeCheck))
{
        exit ("No tienes permisos para ver directamente el archivo");
}

//echo "
//<script language='JavaScript'>
//        function refreshIt(element) {
//                setTimeout(function() {
//                element.src = element.src.split('?')[0] + '?' + new Date().getTime();
//                refreshIt(element);
//              }, 50000); 
//      }
//</script>";

echo "
<script language='JavaScript'>
        function refreshIt(element){
                setInterval(function() {
                element.src = element.src.split('?')[0] + '?' + new Date().getTime();
                }, 50000);
        }
</script>";


?>
```

I include this php file in the pages what I have images and I want to refresh.

I tried the 2 options but as I said, freezes my browser.

Anyone have idea what can I do? Because I need refresh the images only, I don't want to refres the whole page.

## EDIT

Here is the PHP script for print all images in database.

```
<?php

if(!isset($includeCheck))
{
        exit ("No tienes permisos para ver directamente el archivo");
}

if(isset($_GET['freq'])){
        $freq = $_GET['freq'];
        $title = 'Gráficas';
} else {
        exit ("No has especificado la frecuencia");
}

if($freq == "hourly"){
$title = 'Tráfico última hora';
}

if($freq == "daily"){
$title = 'Tráfico último dia';
}

if($freq == "weekly"){
$title = 'Tráfico última semana';
}

if($freq == "monthly"){
$title = 'Tráfico último mes';
}

if($freq == "yearly"){
$title = 'Tráfico último año';
}

if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $limit = $_GET['limit'];
} else {
        $limit="10";
}


if(isset($_GET['inicio'])){
        $inicio = $_GET['inicio'];
}

if(isset($_GET['subpage'])){
        $subpage = $_GET['subpage'];
        if ($subpage==1) {
                $inicio=0;
        }
} else {
        $subpage = "1";
        $inicio="0";

}

$total_records = $conn->query("SELECT graph_id FROM graph_".$freq)->num_rows;
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);


$sql = "SELECT graph_desc,graph_id,graph_name FROM graph_".$freq." ORDER BY graph_desc ASC LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$inicio.";";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

include_once 'adm/includes/pagination.php';

echo "<h1 id='titulo' class=\"page-header\">".$title."</h1>";
include_once 'adm/includes/refresh.php';


if ($total_pages != '1') {
echo "<div id='pager1' class='col-md-12'>";
echo $pagLink;
echo "</div>";
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                echo "
                        <div class='graphSize' style='float:left; position:relative; z-index: 10;'>
                                <a href='?page=GraphDetail&graph_id=".$row['graph_id']."&graph_desc=".$row['graph_desc']."'>
                                        <img style='width:100%' src='/graficas/".$freq."/".$row['graph_name']."' onload='refreshIt(this)'></img>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                ";


        }
}
else {
        echo "<p>No hay ninguna gráfica para mostrar</p>"; }

if ($total_pages != '1') {
echo "<div id='pager2' class='col-md-12'>";
echo $pagLink;
echo "</div>";
}

echo "</body>";

if(isset($_GET['fullscreen'])){
        echo "<style>";
        echo ".graphSize {";
                echo "width:500px;";
        echo "}";
        echo "</style>";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak

Comment: It would be really great to see a full html page which gets rendered and sent to the client. Anyway, my first thought is the you (or your current browser) have a memory leak. Try to monitor how much resources your browser consumes every other 10 minutes.

Comment: Maybe trying to do what @KirillRogovoy suggested and if your browser is consuming a lot of resources trying to cleanInterval and restart the interval again?

Comment: Which browser is having this issue?

Comment: I just added the php code. @Slico as I saw the problem is when the browser tab is not focused the javascript is cached and when I try to reopen the tab, start doing all the cached pollers. I tried with Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this `onload` handler for your image:

```
refreshIt(this)
```

...and that sets an interval (meaning it will repeat) every 50 seconds. The callback for that interval sets the src for the image, which means that `onload` will once again trigger, and you'll again do a set interval. So each time a new version of the image loads, you add another interval, so eventually you'll have tons of duplicating callbacks occurring.

You probably want to use `setTimeout`, or call `refreshIt(this)` once, not on every `onload`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob. I tried the setTimeout function (the commented one in the post) but still unsuccessful. As I understand, the problem here is passed 1 hour I have 72 callbacks for a single image source? If I reset the counter will do the work?

Comment: If you use `setTimeout` and only call it after the last image has loaded, you'll only have one active timer at a time, so that shouldn't be the case. Your previous example called `refreshIt` internally, so that coupled with the `onload` which would have fired each time would have caused the duplicated timeouts. Just get rid of the `refreshIt` call in one place or the other.

Comment: Ok, I tried this `<script language='JavaScript'>
        function refreshIt(element) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                element.src = element.src.split('?')[0] + '?' + new Date().getTime();                refreshIt(element);
              }, 50000); 
      }
</script>`

Comment: Ok, It's working perfectly, Thanks you Jacob. All this for a simple line!