# Using jQuery.text() Causes Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, timer

I am creating a single page application that will remain active and open for multiple days at a time in a browser. On this page I am displaying a timer in the top right corner. I have found however, that the way I am using the timer is leaking a small amount of memory.

https://jsfiddle.net/zbgonp84/

```
$(function(){
    timer();
});
function timer(){
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    $("#timer").text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    var t = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10){
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I have recreated just the timer and the timer's div in a fiddle. If you open chrome's dev tools and record a time line, you can see that every second a new node is added to memory. If left for 24 hours, it will add a new node every second for the whole day and never gets collected.

I feel as if I am missing something fairly obvious as to why this is not being garbage collected, but what am I missing to unallocate the memory?

Comment: Are you referring to `timer` reference and use of `setTimeout`? What is expected result? You are also calling `jQuery()` at each call to `timer`.

Comment: How does `garbage collector` is connected? What garbage it should collect?

Comment: have you tried calling `.empty()` before changing `.text()`

Comment: I am expecting the node count to increase by 1, and then continue to use the same reference. However it seems to be creating a new reference to #timer every time the function runs. Commenting out the $("#timer").text() line prevents any new nodes from being created. @u_mulder I expect it to collect the old $("#timer") reference.

Comment: @Steve I just tried adding .empty before .text, however the nodes continue to increase. How would i reference the timer every call without calling jQuery() on each call?

Comment: Isn't this just a case of the dev tools showing the increase of nodes since it collects the stack traces of the `setTimeout` callback? There's no actual memory leak, it's just how the timeline recording works and how it's reflected in the tool.

Comment: http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html

Comment: @Daniel B It seems you may be right. Although calling .empty() on the element before keeps the js heap down. So a combination of the two seem to have resolved my minor issue. Thanks for the help, seems my issue lies elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Cool! Found a similar issue, almost certain the same applies here! [Does JavaScript setInterval() method cause memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak/14851513#14851513)

Comment: Good read, looks like i got caught up whether or not Jquery or my code was causing issues, and missed that it could have been chrome itself and how I was interpreting the timeline. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and substitute a reference to `#timer` element for calling `jQuery()` at each call to `timer`. Also, declare variable `t` outside of `timer`

```
$(function() {
  const time = $("#timer");
  var t;
  timer();

  function timer() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    time.text(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
    t = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
  }

  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10){
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
  }
});
```

Comment: Adjusting my code to use this as well, may save me any worry that my memory will be increasing too much. Thanks!

Comment: line 5 (`});` ) may need moving to the end of the block  to put `const time` in scope of  `timer` :-)

Comment: @Traktor53 Updated