# Memory growth react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My app includes only one home screen, and it should run for a long period of time(In kiosk mode, for weeks).

After a while, I have noticed that it is crashing due to memory growth(it became something like 500,000K).
I started to investigate this bug, and created a simplified version of this app: one component that all it does is changing the UI every 500ms, and ran it over night.

My component code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';


let counter = 0;

const Home = ({
}) => {
  // State
  const [param1, setParam1] = useState(0);
  const [param2, setParam2] = useState(0);
  const [param3, setParam3] = useState(0);
  const [param4, setParam4] = useState(0);
  const [param5, setParam5] = useState(0);
  const [param6, setParam6] = useState(0);

  // Effects
  useEffect(() => {
    // <- component did mount + unmount equivalent
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      counter += 1;
      setParam1(counter)
      setParam2(counter)
      setParam3(counter)
      setParam4(counter)
      setParam5(counter)
      setParam6(counter)
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    };
  }, []);

  const connectivitySummary = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{param1}</Text>
        <Text>{param2}</Text>
        <Text>{param3}</Text>
        <Text>{param4}</Text>
        <Text>{param5}</Text>
        <Text>{param6}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View>{connectivitySummary()}</View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The result is:
[UI result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlvQR.png)

When I started to run this app, memory usage was around ***46,000k***.

After a night running, memory usage is ***214,338K***:

[My app name is Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNUla.png)

Can someone please tell me what am I missing? why this huge memory growth happening?

About setInterval: I know that setInterval can cause memory leaks, but the GC suppose to clear it(please check [Does JavaScript setInterval() method cause memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak))

React Native version: 0.60.5

Thank you for your help!!